# Oracle DB connection error with Python - cx_Oracle: cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

After trying to connect to DB with cx_Oracle.connect(...) I get the following exception: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client Library: "...path" is not the correct architecture.
I am also given a link where there are some info about the libraries and about the fact that Oracle Client libraries "require the presence of the correct Visual Studio redistributable".
The thing is that the only thing I have (where I actually create the DB itself) is Oracle SqlDeveloper. 
So.. do I really need to install smth to get it to work?

Comment: Do you have a question about the instructions on the link? They tell you what to download and where to get it.  You may also want to read the cx_Oracle installation instructions https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html which contain the same info.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your python is 32bit & looking for 32bit cx_Oracle.
2. You need to install Visual Studio & cx_Oracle.
   Refer to [this site](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scohen/cs327e_spr15/cx_Oracle/windows.html) and download the 32 bit cx_oracle `.zip` & the VS `.exe`.
3. Install the VS `.exe` (double click to install).
4. Unzip the cx_oracle zip, put it into your python installation folder, eg.

   ```
   C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
   ```

   to get to this directory

   ```
   C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\instantclient_19_3\
   ```
5. Set your computer/machine `PATH` in "environment variable" to include

   ```
   C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\instantclient_19_3
   ```
6. Restart your machine.